# How to put boundaries to QR code? (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'll work on an hybrid html5 app (Cordova) and I want to make a qr barcode scanner (without the classic brackets) that get the qr value AND the coordinates of each corner points.

Any advice to get the coordinates? (example or plugin)

I saw that the default qr scanner of windows phone achieves what I want:
[image: Windows Phone qr preview]

Thank you all.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: I'm looking for advices because I dont want to waste time choosing a wrong plugin. I only developed  functions non related to the camera nor the question either.